# Photon absorbsion through 'quantum foam'

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

Over the cosmological distances that the photons travel from distant sources, will 'quantum foam' have an effect on them before they reach us?

***Re NASA Science News Dec 31st 2015.**

The effect on Photons travelling through ‘quantum foam’.

Perlman says that “Over the cosmological distances that the photons travel from these distant sources, the effects of the fluctuations the photons encounter will accumulate. The more they accumulate, the more out of phase the light will get.  Creating an image from a collection of such photons would be like trying to distinguish what one person is saying in a huge crowd of people talking. So it would be physically impossible to get a clear picture.”*

Comment: Godlike question. :-) (I.e. only God knows :-) ) This is the probable reason, why you got 3 downs. Another reason, that your single-sentence question would require a page long answer from a high level string theorist. But if you've luck, maybe one of them will answer it. Actually, I am curious to the answer, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it wont. Quantum foam is a theoretical effect, which occurs when you try to unify General Relativity and Quantum Field Theory. Today there are a few mathematial ways to provide such effects (elements of String-Theory, Quantum Field Theories formulated on topology changing Spacetimes).

There is also an effect similar to this one in Loop Quantum Gravity, which predicts that light has to change its wavelength while traveling a long cosmological distance because of the knot structure of Spacetime.